# Performance difference between mobile models having same chipset, RAM and OS

Tags: load-testing, mobile, performance-testing

According to [this article](https://www.91mobiles.com/hub/oneplus-7-pro-most-powerful-phone-antutu-june-2019/), One Plus 7 Pro scores higher than One Plus 7 in performance benchmarking. Looking at the specs I found that both the models have exactly same chipset, RAM and Operating System.

How can there be a difference in the performance in such a scenario? What other factors can affect the device's performance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be a testing related issue

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **every** empirical analysis is fragile to factors out of the modeling:

Every model of how things work is necessarily a sub-set of factors than the whole reality. For some fields, such as physics, we can model things with fairly security. Economics, on the other hand, [have already discover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Use_of_Knowledge_in_Society) than analytical approach is more appropriated.

Now, talking about devices, even the room temperature can affect a performance. The software installation may affect the benchmarking.

Also, I [couldn't find](https://github.com/antutu) the source code for the AnTuTu tool for Android.
Therefore, we can't say how this experiment was conducted.

Comment: But two different models using same chipset, same amount of RAM and same OS practically shouldn't have any difference in performance right?

Comment: Above, I meant "model" of reality. Every experiment demands a certain simplification of reality, and the process of defining this simplification may ended up destroying the validity of the experiment. An example of this simplification is when a high school physics teacher makes calculations "ignoring friction and under normal pressure conditions".
I just start talking about cellphones on the third paragraph.

Comment: I was looking for a simplified answer. Something that holds in a general sense. I appreciate your concern about the destruction of the validity of the experiment in the process of simplification but in practical life simplification is required. Otherwise we'll be bogged down with loads of details. I was looking for a general simplified answer.